# How to use a variable as a className inside preg_match_all parameters?

Tags: regex

I am using regular expression to get the text inside a single p tag targeting its class. the problem is I want to use a php variable as class name and use a loop to change the class name each time.

```php
$sample = get_the_content(); 


<button class="accordion">
preg_match('/<strong class="1">(.*?)<\/strong>/s', $sample, $match); 
echo $match[1]; 


$className = "1";
```

I want to use the $classname varialbe up there and increment it in a loop to get different paragraph content each time.

I hope I am clear in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this question is not related to WordPress, but rather to PHP directly and should be asked at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) but I have provided a very basic answer below to help you on your way. However be aware that this answer **is not necessarily the best way** to go about solving your problem, **nor is it meant to be efficient**.

```php
// assuming get_the_content() equates to ↓

$content = '<p class="1">P1 Content</p><p class="2">P2 Content</p><p class="3">P3 Content</p>';

$classNames = ['1', '2', '3'];

$matches = [];

foreach( $classNames as $className ) {

    $pattern = sprintf('\<p\sclass=\"%s\"\>(.*?)\<\/p\>', $className);

    preg_match("/{$pattern}/i", $content, $found); 

    $matches[] = $found;

}

var_dump($matches);

/*
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "<p class="1">P1 Content</p>"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "P1 Content"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "<p class="2">P2 Content</p>"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "P2 Content"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "<p class="3">P3 Content</p>"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "P3 Content"
  }
}
*/
```

### UPDATE 1:

If you do not have a fixed, known-list (ahead of time) of class names, then use the following example which utilises `preg_match_all` and looks for any `<P>` tag with `class = NUMBER`.

```html
<p class="1">Content</p>
<p class="2">Content</p>
<!-- etc.. -->
<p class="234">Content</p>
```

```php
$content = '<p class="1">P1 Content</p><p class="2">P2 Content</p><p class="3">P3 Content</p>';

$pattern = sprintf('\<p\sclass=\"%s\"\>(.*?)\<\/p\>', '[0-9]+');

var_dump($pattern);

preg_match_all("/{$pattern}/i", $content, $found);

var_dump($found);

/*
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "<p class="1">P1 Content</p>"
    [1]=>
    string(27) "<p class="2">P2 Content</p>"
    [2]=>
    string(27) "<p class="3">P3 Content</p>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "P1 Content"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "P2 Content"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "P3 Content"
  }
}
*/
```

```php
/**
 * Iterate over the results (if any) and do something with the content.
 */
if ( is_array($found) && isset($found[1]) ) {

    foreach( $found[1] as $content ) {

        echo $content;

    }

}
```

Results in:

```html
P1 Content
P2 Content
P3 Content
```

I advise that you prefix your class names such as:

```html
<p class="myprefix-1">Content</p>
<p class="myprefix-2">Content</p>
<!-- etc.. -->
<p class="myprefix-234">Content</p>
```

If so, make sure to update your regex pattern:

```php
$pattern = sprintf('\<p\sclass=\"myprefix-%s\"\>(.*?)\<\/p\>', '[0-9]+');
```

#### [REPL.IT DEMO](https://repl.it/@fundemental/WPSE356165)

Comment: Thanks dear Adam for you relpy. After i lot of searching and experimenting, I finally found the solution for it. I like to share it here to help others

Comment: @Ashur see **UPDATE 1** in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ashur No problem. I've added a REPL.IT link that you can play with the example above live [HERE](https://repl.it/@fundemental/WPSE356165). Be sure to close out this question by marking the correct answer when you are done.

Comment: alright, but unfortunately I cant do that. because my reputation is very low to do that yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my question and I like to share it:

for this I simply created a php variable and added that in the middle of the parameter:

```php
$sample = get_the_content(); 

$classes = '1';
<button class="accordion">
preg_match('/<p class="'.$classes.'">(.*?)<\/p>/s', $sample, $match); 
echo $match[1];
```

I am still confused how to increment the class by 1 to get different content each time.

Comment: What are the class names of your `<p>` tags? Are they literally `class="1"`, `class="2"`, `class="3"` etc?

Comment: yes, it is. That's why i want to increment it by 1 each time to target a new paragraph each time.

Answer (score 0):

Dear "Adam" this is what I am trying to do but I have issue in the length of array.

```php
$tkey = 'post-update';

$update = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tag' => $tkey
));

wp_reset_postdata();

if ($update->have_posts()) {
    while ($update->have_posts()) {
        $update->the_post();
        $sample = get_the_content();
    }
}

$classes = array();
array_push($classes, $match);

foreach ($classes as $names => $text) {

?>
    <button class="accordion">
        <?php
        preg_match('/<strong class="' . $text . '">(.*?)<\/strong>/s', $sample, $match);
        echo $match[1];
        ?>
    </button>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>
            <?php
            preg_match('/<p class="' . $text . '">(.*?)<\/p>/s', $sample, $match);
            echo $match[1];
            ?>
        </p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the edits. I have problem to display the question properly.

Comment: Do you have any solution for dynamically selecting the length of the $classes array according to the number of paragraphs that will be pulled out from the post?